# Increasing Upload File Size Limit in Google Cloud

Tags: wordpress, upload-max-filesize

I am trying to increase upload file size limit in Google Cloud.

I open nano /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini and increase upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

I also restart the apache by sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache

Retart also works well, so I am sure the code is correct. But when I am trying to upload the file in WordPress backend, it says Maximum upload file size is 40MB.

I am trying to migrate a website by All in one WP migration plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the values you actually set the variables to? Also remember that the figure for 'memory_limit' has to be higher than of 'post_max_size' according to this documentation: http://www.projectweb.gr/seoblog/import-large-sql-databases-with-phpmyadmin-increase-size-limit/

Comment: This is not an issue with Google Cloud. This is an issue with WordPress and PHP. This question has been asked and answered many times on the WordPress forum. Move your question to here after reviewing the other answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I change both to 128m, I read the other articles and they usually suggest to keep them the same.

I also tried edit the limit in other servers, and usually we can do it by robot.txt or wp_config.php, but those options are not working here in Google Cloud, that's why I thought this is the issue because of the server.

Plus, even after changing the limit in /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini, it still shows as 40MB.

Answer (score 0):

Do a full restart and not just the Apache restart as one of the user had commented using the below command.
“sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart”